# Select one record per minute

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by

I'm looking for a way to get the Entity Framework to return one record for every minute in a database field e.g. for the table below:

```
Message | Timestamp
--------+--------------------
a       | 2011-01-02 12:31:10
b       | 2011-01-02 12:31:15
c       | 2011-01-02 12:31:59
d       | 2011-01-02 12:32:01
e       | 2011-01-02 12:32:30
f       | 2011-01-02 12:33:10
```

I want a query that returns

```
c,e,f (c and e are selected because they are the latest entries)
```

Is this possibly with a single query? The database is quite large so I don't want to retrieve all records and select them in a loop.

Comment: Group by year, month, day, hour, minute. Sort values by timestamp. Select first entry in each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Linq for an in-memory collection instead of EF, but you should be able to adapt this easily.

```
    private static void LinqExample()
    {
        var a = new object[]
                    {
                        new object[] {"a", DateTime.Parse(" 2011-01-02 12:31:10")},
                        new object[] {"b", DateTime.Parse(" 2011-01-02 12:31:15")},
                        new object[] {"c", DateTime.Parse(" 2011-01-02 12:31:59")},
                        new object[] {"d", DateTime.Parse(" 2011-01-02 12:32:01")},
                        new object[] {"e", DateTime.Parse(" 2011-01-02 12:32:30")},
                        new object[] {"f", DateTime.Parse(" 2011-01-02 12:33:10")},
                    };

        var result = from pair in a
                     let msg = (string) ((object[]) pair)[0]
                     let date = (DateTime) ((object[]) pair)[1]
                     group new {date, msg} by new {date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, date.Hour, date.Minute}
                     into dateGroup
                     select dateGroup.OrderBy(dg => dg.date).Last();

        foreach (var res in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res.msg);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the exact syntax but below could help. You can tune it further for sql performance.

Select * from sometable where id in (select maxid from sometable group by Date, Hour, Min)

Comment: If you have many entries in that table, i would suggest splitting up the timestamp into date, hour, minutes (and seconds if you need that) for better performance

Comment: Maybe DATEPART can help you.... http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: @Thomas He didnt say LINQ in particular. You can write a SP and call it from Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    MAX([Message]) 
FROM 
    [Messages]
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(yyyy, [Timestamp])
    ,DATEPART(mm, [Timestamp])
    ,DATEPART(dd, [Timestamp])
    ,DATEPART(hh, [Timestamp])
    ,DATEPART(mi, [Timestamp])
```

This assumes that the Message column correlates with the Timestamp column as your sample data shows.

**UPDATE**:

Just saw that this is looking for EF, not straight SQL. @Ross appears to have the answer for a LINQ query. I'll leave the SQL here for reference.